# How to get sequence number in map function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way for me to get the sequence number of each item in a `map` function in JavaScript?

For example, I have an array of 5 items and would like to pass the sequence number of each item to my React component in the following code:

```
{toDoList.map(item => <ToDoItem key={item.id} sequenceNumber={???} data={item} />)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the three parameters to callback function inside map are element, index and array itself, so you only need to give a second argument to callback function like:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr.map((num, index) => console.log(num + " " + index));
```

so in your case it will be:

```
{toDoList.map((item, index) => <ToDoItem key={item.id} sequenceNumber={index} data={item} />)}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use `.map`, your function actually gets passed in 3 parameters: the item of the array, it's index, and the array itself. [See more here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

So that index should work for your sequence number:

```
{toDoList.map((item, index) => 
    <ToDoItem key={item.id} sequenceNumber={index} data={item} />)}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the second parameter of the callback.

```
[101,102,103].map((a,b)=>b)
```

gives [0,1,2]

Answer (score 1):

You can use array index as a sequence of number.

```
{toDoList.map((item, index) => 
    <ToDoItem key={item.id} sequenceNumber={index} data={item} />)}
```